# VB.NET Esperar a que termine un audio y luego cerrar la app

Tags: vb.net

Tengo una app en VB.NET Framework 3.5 en la que podes poner la ruta de un archivo .wav y después en otro form lo reproduce con este comando:

`My.Computer.Audio.Play(Module1.ModuleSong, AudioPlayMode.Background)`

Y nose como hacer para que espere a que termine ese audio y después cerrar la aplicación ¿Qué maneras hay para hacer eso?

Answer (score 0):

Para VB.NET Framework 3.5 no parece posible. Pero si compilas con la versión 4.5 o superior la solución parece ser la siguiente:

```
    Class LockingWithAwait
    Public Sub Test()
        doSomething() ' hacer alguna tarea
    End Sub

    Private Sub doSomething()
        Dim t As Task = Task.Run(Sub() PlayTheMusicWithLock())
        t.Wait()
        CallSubMethodHere() ' Cuando termine la música llama a CallSubMethodHere()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PlayTheMusicWithLock()
        Dim miArchivoWAV As String =
            "C:\...\Music\airplane-landing_daniel_simion.wav"
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(miArchivoWAV, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CallSubMethodHere()
        Console.WriteLine("Aquí cerrarías el formulario")
        ' Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Para la llamada al método de la clase:

```
    Dim t As New LockingWithAwait
    t.Test()
```